# Not getting full http response in android

Tags: android

I am try to get json  data from ulr .

I am testing url in firefox poster add-on work fine ,getting full response .

But in **android not getting full http response .**

**this my code**

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(client.getParams(), 10000); // Timeout
                                                                        // Limit
HttpResponse response;
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

try {
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(API.ALL_PROPERTY_BUY);

    /*
     * json.put("fId", fname); json.put("fId", lname);
     */
    StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json.toString());
    se.setContentType(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE,"application/json"));
    post.setEntity(se);
    response = client.execute(post);

    /* Checking response */
    if (response != null) {
        InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent(); // Get the
                                                            // data in
                                                            // the
                                                            // entity
        // System.out.println("Response is:"+ in.toString());
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(in);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

        String s = new String();
        temps = new String();
        while ((s = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println("response is :" + s);

        }



    }


} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();

}
```

I am also search from google and try code but not solve my problem.

please any one help me.

Comment: add internet permission in manifest file.

Comment: @VivekKumarSrivastava all permission add and my code work fine but problem is not getting full response from webservice .

Comment: you can use String s = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()); and let me know if this work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this...

```
    StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
            while ((s = br.readLine()) != null) {
                stringBuffer.append(s);
            }

 System.out.println("response is :" + stringBuffer);
```

Sometimes its not print full response on console  but you get full response in your variable...

**Solution : Full Data not shown on Logcat or Console**

Comment: your response is very large to limit of variable ? means you get response half or not getting any response pls specify...? Thanks

Comment: getting half response.because my response size is very large.

Comment: as @SBJ said..full response data do not show in log cat..so try to set data into TextView.  You can try String s = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()); to get response instead of InputStream.

Comment: @SBJ is there any specific limit to print the data in logcat? please let me know thank you ...